# Bind a directive's isolated scope to an inner object of the controller's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I return the following from the directive's function:

```
return {
    scope: {
        sometag: "="
    },
    link: link
}
```

And I set up the directive as follows:

```
<div myDirective sometag="david"> </div>
```

And I have this line in my controller:

```
$scope.david = {firstName: "david", lastName: "McGee"};
```

Then from the directive's link function I'm able to do this:

```
console.log(scope.sometag.firstName + " " + scope.sometag.lastName);
```

But what if I have a collection in my **controller**, maybe something like this:

```
$scope.movies = {
    aNewHope: { title: "A New Hope", rating: 4},
    theEmpire: { title: "The Empire Strikes Back", rating: 5},
    returnOfJedi: { title: "Return of the Jedi", rating: 3}
}
```

And I want to point my directive to a movie within that collection so that if my **directive** has this in it's link function:

```
console.log(scope.movie.title + " has rating of " + scope.movie.rating);
```

This as the isolated scope:

```
return {
    scope: {
        movie: "="
    }
}
```

And I'm setting it up like this:

```
<div myDirective movie="aNewHope"> </div>
```

Then the following will appear in console:

```
A New Hope has rating of 4
```

Maybe more simply put, how do I walk in one extra step within the controller's scope so I'll have access to it in the directive's isolated scope?

---

To make things more clear, my full intent is as follows:

The collection I was referring to is an answer from the server. I am then using ng-repeat to populate a list. I also want to bind to each item of that list a click event that will query more data about that movie using the movieID (the key in the above collection). So I figured instead telling ng-repeat to repeat `<li>` elements, I'll tell it to repeat a `<my-directive>` element and I'll bind the click event from there. I just need a way to tell my directive which argument am I sending to the function. I would like the function to be executed under the controller's scope and not from the directive.

Comment: Really depends on more information about how you plan to use whole collection....or if you only intend to present one item. For example within `ng-repeat` you already have array element instance access defined in repeat quesry

Comment: I actually am using it with ng-repeat. I don't understand what you meant when you said that I already have an array element instance access though. I edited my question to include more information about my end-goal.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this

```
<div myDirective movie="aNewHope"> </div>
```

'aNewHope' refers to an (unexistent) property of the $scope object in your controller.

```
console.log(scope.movie) // -> undefined
```

Since you're trying to give your directive's isolate scope a property name, you need to pass it as a string.

There's two different ways of doing this.

(1) Hand it through an Angular expression

```
<div myDirective movie="{{ "aNewHope" }}"> </div>
```

or (2) A variable "movieTitle" set to the key of the movie as a string

```
$scope.movieTitle = "aNewHope"

<div myDirective movie="movieTitle"> </div>
```

However, doing so would result in getting the following output in console:

```
undefined has rating of undefined
```

As you might have guessed, that's because 'scope.movie' is now set to a string, and it doesn't have the properties 'name' or 'rating'.
What you're trying to get, is a property of the collection that's in the controller. But, because of isolate scope, the directive does not have access to it. In your first example, you were passing your directive the whole 'david' object, which is why it was able to access it's properties. You can do the same with your collection:

```
<div myDirective movies="movies" movie="movieTitle"> </div>
```

The collection is now accessible from the isolate scope. You can then use square brackets to get an object's property from a variable.

```
console.log(scope.movies[movie].title + " has rating of " + scope.movies[movie].title);
```